# Qpython unicode strings

Tags: android, python, unicode-string, qpython

I'm trying to port a Python 3.5 project from PC to Android QPython3 but for the line:-

```
if ch = in u'\x00\xe0':
    ch = getwch()
```

I'm getting this when I run it:-

```
if ch = in u'\x00\xe0':
                ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I thought `QPython3` was supposed to run all 3.x scripts and the Unicode `'u'` prefix isn't a new addition so what can the problem be?  Are hex numbers in strings treated differently?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, after much fiddling about I got it to work using:-

`if ch in bytes([0x00, 0xe0]):`

instead.